# Remove text after "(" in a .txt file

Tags: python, python-3.x, text, notepad++, text-files

I want to delete everything in my .txt file that starts with "(", / maybe in python / for example:

Default txt file:

```
hello:123(123.3232)
```

Output:

```
hello:123
```

And i want to do that with over 100 lines with Notepad++, "(.*" doesnt work, it says invalid characters

Comment: Do you want to do it in Python or Notepad++? If it's the latter, your question is [off-topic](/help/on-topic). Stack Overflow is intended for _specific programming questions_. Please read [ask] and provide a [mre] highlighting your _specific_ problem. Notepad++ says "invalid regular expression" because you need to escape the `(` with a backslash.

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
“Show me how to solve this coding problem” is not a Stack Overflow issue.  We expect you to make an honest attempt, and *then* ask a *specific* question about your algorithm or technique.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation and tutorials.  Whether you need tutorial help in Notepad, or a Python script, the question is currently out of scope for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

As you have mentioned you are doing this in Notepad++ we will use that. Open 'find and replace', tick regular expression on the bottom, and use the find term `\(.*`  Finally hit replace all.

edit: due to formatting, the expression was showing as `(.*`, the correct term is `\(.*`

Comment: You don't really need the capturing group. `\(.*` should also work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the regex module to do those

```
import re
st = 'hello:123(123.3232)'
st = re.sub('\(.*','',st)
print(st)
```

that gives the answer as

```
hello:123
```